# CommandphaseScript execution failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I recently updated my Xcode to version 14.3, and started receiving the error "source: unbound variable Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" whenever I try to **Archive** the **Swift** Xcode project with ios deployment taget 13.0.

Below are the things working:

- Building while in "Any iOS device"
- Able to run in iphone 14 simulator

Here is the error below:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/dhiralpanjwani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lupus_Decision_Aid-haxtkzwojyytuwedvxiexocoohxi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid.build/Release-iphoneos/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid.build/Script-570BD887603D2E782013C015.sh (in target 'Lupus Decision Aid' from project 'Lupus Decision Aid') cd /Users/dhiralpanjwani/Downloads/iOS/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid\ copy /bin/sh -c /Users/dhiralpanjwani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lupus_Decision_Aid-haxtkzwojyytuwedvxiexocoohxi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid.build/Release-iphoneos/Lupus\ Decision\ Aid.build/Script-570BD887603D2E782013C015.sh

mkdir -p /Users/dhiralpanjwani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lupus_Decision_Aid-haxtkzwojyytuwedvxiexocoohxi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Lupus Decision Aid/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Lupus Decision Aid.app/Frameworks /Users/dhiralpanjwani/Downloads/iOS/Lupus Decision Aid copy/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Lupus Decision Aid/Pods-Lupus Decision Aid-frameworks.sh: line 43: **source: unbound variable Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

I have tried following things:

- pod deintegrate; pod install (pod version 1.12.1)
- Build settings -> Excluded Architectures-> Delete "arm64
- Adding '-f' in the frameworks.sh file
- Reinstalling xcode 14.1